# Memory Latency Specs Utility?

Tags: windows-vista, memory, specifications

Is there a utility that can tell me the latency of the RAM I'm using? I'm using Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php). Under the `Memory` tab there is a section for timings.